# Prove that Banach algebra $B(X)$ has a unique (up to equivalence) complete algebra norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-algebras

> Let $X$ be a Banach Space, and denote by $∥ · ∥$ the standard norm on
>   $B(X)$, the space of bounded linear functions $T:X\to X$.
>
> (a) Suppose that $||| · |||$ is another algebra norm on $B(X)$. Prove
>   that there exists $C > 0$ such that $∥ · ∥ ≤ C||| · |||$.
>
> (b) Prove that B(X) has a unique (up to equivalence) complete algebra
>   norm.

For (a), 
Assume not, then $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \exists T_n \in \mathcal{B}(X)$, such that $\|T_n\|> n|||T_n|||$, so scale $T_n$ such that $|||T_n||| = 1, \|T_n\|> n$.

$\forall x_0\in X, \lambda\in X^*$, define $S = x_0\lambda, S(x) = \lambda(x)x_0$, then $|S(x)| = |\lambda(x)| \|x_0\| \le \|\lambda\|\|x_0\|    \|x\|$, so $\|S\|\le \|\lambda\|\|x_0\|$, and so $S$ is a bounded functional on $X$.

$\forall R \in \mathcal{B}(X), \forall x\in X, (SRS)(x) = S(R(\lambda(x)x_0)) = \lambda(x)\lambda(Rx_0)x_0 = (\lambda(Rx_0)S)(x)$, so $SRS =     \lambda(Rx_0)S$. And so 
$$|||SRS||| = |\lambda(Rx_0)|\cdot|||S||| \le |||S|||\cdot|||R|||\cdot|||S|||.$$
 When $S\neq 0, |\lambda(Rx_0)| \le |||S|||\cdot|||R|||$.

Since $|||T_n||| = 1, |\lambda(T_n x_0)| \le |||S|||$. Then let $T'_n = T_n/\|T_n\|$, then $|\lambda(T_n'x_0)| \to 0$,

So $\forall x_0\in X, T_n' x_0 \rightharpoonup 0$ weakly. Thus...???

For (b), assume (a). It remains to show that if $|||\cdot |||$ is a complete norm, then $|||\cdot ||| \le D ||\cdot ||$ for some D. 
A proof by contradiction starts by finding a sequence $T_n$ such that $|||T_n||| = 1$, 
$||T_n|| \to 0$, but this does not lead to anything contradictory.

Johnson (1967) [THE UNIQUENESS OF THE (COMPLETE)
NORM TOPOLOGY](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183528950) shows a related result, but I don't find it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part one, continue from "When $S≠0,|λ(Rx_0)|≤|||S|||⋅|||R|||$.".

Let $R = T_n$, then use Uniform Boundedness Principle to find $x_0\in X$ such that $(T_nx_0)_n$ is unbounded, then use Uniform Boundedness Principle again to find $\lambda \in X^*$ such that $(\lambda(T_nx_0))_n$ is unbounded, and that's a contradiction.

This was based on a hint from [page 45](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=-xIkW4Feg4MC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=Eidelheit%20unique%20norm%201940#v=onepage&q=Eidelheit%20unique%20norm%201940&f=false) of *Introduction to Banach Algebras, Operators, and Harmonic Analysis* (2003) by George A. Willis, H. G. Dales, Jörg Eschmeier, Kjeld Laursen, and Pietro Aiena.

For part (b), use open mapping theorem on the identity map $id: (X, \|\cdot\|)\to (X, |||\cdot|||)$, which is bounded by part (a).

Answer (score 2):

For part b): if you have two complete norms $\|.\|_1$ and $\|.\|_2$ on a space $Y$ such that $\|.\|_1 \leq C\|.\|_2$ then the two norms are automatically equivalent. This is immediate from Open Mapping Theorem. [Consider the identity map from $(Y,\|.\|_2) \to (Y,\|.\|_1)$.]